# Why is my bundle ignoring its info.plist?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbundle, macos

I am attempting to bundle a set of resources into a bundle, and them access them from code via NSBundle.

So far, I can access the resources from the bundle fine, but I cannot get the NSBundle instance to get any meta-data from the bundle's Info.plist file.

Strangely, my first attempt worked, and correctly got the meta-data, but since then I have been unable to replicate this behaviour and the bundle always returns null for the bundleIdentifier or other items in the infoDictionary.

I have reduced the code to the following test case:

```
NSString *pathToTestBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" 
                                                    ofType:@"testBundle"];
NSLog(@"path to Test Bundle: %@", pathToTestBundle);

NSBundle *testBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath: pathToTestBundle];
NSLog(@"testBundle: %@", testBundle);

NSString *identifier = [testBundle bundleIdentifier];
NSLog(@"testBundle identifier: %@", identifier);

NSURL *testResourceURL = [testBundle URLForResource:@"vanGroup" 
                                       withExtension:@"png"];
NSLog(@"testBundle test resource: %@", testResourceURL);

NSImage *testImage = [[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingURL:testResourceURL]; 
[imageView setImage:testImage];

NSLog(@"%@", [testBundle infoDictionary]);
```

Which gives this: (edited for line length)

```
path to Test Bundle: /.../BundleTester.app/Contents/Resources/test.testBundle
testBundle: NSBundle </../BundleTester.app/Contents/Resources/test.testBundle> 
      (not yet loaded)
testBundle identifier: (null)
testBundle test resource: file://.../BundleTester.app/Contents/Resources/test.testBundle/Resources/vanGroup.png
BundleTester[45083:707] {
    NSBundleInitialPath = "/Users/diggory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BundleTester-hcbsnhudsdfzlyggjbvlkdbrtxrw/Build/Products/Debug/BundleTester.app/Contents/Resources/test.testBundle";
    NSBundleResolvedPath = "/Users/diggory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BundleTester-hcbsnhudsdfzlyggjbvlkdbrtxrw/Build/Products/Debug/BundleTester.app/Contents/Resources/test.testBundle";
}
```

In my Xcode project by test bundle is added as a folder reference and has the following structure:

```
test.testBundle
    Info.plist
    Resources
        vanGroup.png
```

The image resource is loaded correctly, but the values in the plist are ignored.

The plist is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.monkeyfood.testbundle</string>
    <key>badger</key>
    <string>Bodger</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Am I missing something?  What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks.

Comment: I've never used bundles. However doesn't every bundle contain a "Contents" folder in it? Why are you using bundles at all?

Comment: Brilliant - I had forgotten the Contents folder.  It works now, thanks very much.

Comment: Added an answer so it's official :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Contents" folder is missing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `bundle` object is referring to the Bundle but the Bundle isn't yet loaded which is why you get null when you call bundleIdentifier. From Apple's Documentation on Bundle Loading Code

> To load a bundle’s executable code, use NSBundle’s load method. This method returns YES if loading was successful or if the code had already been loaded, and NO otherwise.

You need to call `[bundle load]` like so:

```
NSBundle *testBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath: pathToTestBundle];
[testBundle load];   // Load the bundle...
```

More information on [Bundle Loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Tasks/LoadingBundles.html) is explained in Apple's Documentation

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There is no code in the bundle.  It's just a resource bundle containing images etc..  Calling `load` doesn't change the behaviour.